# CLisp: set encoding to UTF-8 for strings

Tags: unicode, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have some piece of code:

```
; Palatal Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "ɲ")
                    '(:plosive "c") '(:plosive "ɟ")
                    '(:fricative "ç") '(:fricative "ʝ")
                    '(:approximant "j")
                    '(:lateral-fricative "ʎ̥˔")
                    '(:lateral-approximant "ʎ")
                    '(:lateral-flap "ʎ̯") ) do
    (add-sound :palatal (car e) (cadr e)))
```

I have a lot of these bits for all IPA symbols, this isn't specifically the problem one.

However, attempting to run my code gives this error:

> SYSTEM::STRING-READER: Invalid byte #x90 in CHARSET:CP1252 conversion

Which is fine, except I cannot find a way to, WITHIN the script file, tell CLisp that I am typing strings in UTF-8, and I want it to read them and print them in UTF-8.

How do I globally, permanently set UTF-8. I am thinking similarly to Ruby's `# encoding: utf-8`

Specifically I am using CLisp 2.48.

EDIT:

Here is the full source listing for the file that causes the issue:

```
(defstruct sound place means sym)
(defparameter $sounds nil)
(defun add-sound (place means sym)
  (setf $sounds (append $sounds (list (make-sound :place place :means means :sym sym)))))
; There are alot of IPA symbols, so we'll add them column by column.
; The first column is the Bilabial Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                  '(:nasal "m") '(:plosive "p")
                  '(:plosive "b") '(:fricative "ɸ")
                  '(:fricative "β") '(:trill "ʙ")
                  '(:flap "ⱱ̟") ) do
  (add-sound :bilabial (car e) (cadr e)))
; Labiodental Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "ɱ") '(:plosive "p̪")
                    '(:plosive "b̪") '(:fricative "f")
                    '(:fricative "v") '(:approximant "ʋ")
                    '(:flap "ⱱ") ) do
    (add-sound :labiodental (car e) (cadr e)))
; Dental Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "n̪")
                    '(:plosive "t̪") '(:plosive "d̪")
                    '(:fricative "θ") '(:fricative "ð") ) do
    (add-sound :dental (car e) (cadr e)))
; Alveolar Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "n")
                    '(:plosive "t") '(:plosive "d")
                    '(:fricative "s") '(:fricative "z")
                    '(:trill "r")
                    '(:flap "ɾ")
                    '(:lateral-fricative "ɬ") '(:lateral-fricative "ɮ")
                    '(:lateral-approximant "l")
                    '(:lateral-flap "ɺ") ) do
    (add-sound :alveolar (car e) (cadr e)))
; Palato-Alveolar Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:fricative "ʃ") '(:fricative "ʒ")
                    '(:approximant "ɹ") ) do
    (add-sound :palato-alveolar (car e) (cadr e)))
; Retroflex Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "ɳ")
                    '(:plosive "ʈ") '(:plosive "ɖ")
                    '(:fricative "ʂ") '(:fricative "ʐ")
                    '(:approximant "ɻ")
                    '(:trill "ɽ͡r")
                    '(:flap "ɽ")
                    '(:lateral-fricative "ɭ˔̊")
                    '(:lateral-approximant "ɭ")
                    '(:lateral-flap "ɺ̢") ) do
    (add-sound :retroflex (car e) (cadr e)))
; Palatal Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "ɲ")
                    '(:plosive "c") '(:plosive "ɟ")
                    '(:fricative "ç") '(:fricative "ʝ")
                    '(:approximant "j")
                    '(:lateral-fricative "ʎ̥˔")
                    '(:lateral-approximant "ʎ")
                    '(:lateral-flap "ʎ̯") ) do
    (add-sound :palatal (car e) (cadr e)))
; Velar Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "ŋ")
                    '(:plosive "k") '(:plosive "ɡ")
                    '(:fricative "x") '(:fricative "ɣ")
                    '(:approximant "ɰ")
                    '(:lateral-fricative "ʟ̝̊")
                    '(:lateral-approximant "ʟ") ) do
    (add-sound :velar (car e) (cadr e)))
; Uvular Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:nasal "ɴ")
                    '(:plosive "q") '(:plosive "ɢ")
                    '(:fricative "χ") '(:fricative "ʁ")
                    '(:trill "ʀ")
                    '(:flap "ɢ̆") ) do
    (add-sound :uvular (car e) (cadr e)))
; Pharyngeal Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:plosive "ʡ")
                    '(:fricative "ħ") '(:fricative "ʕ")
                    '(:trill "ʜ") '(:trill "ʢ")
                    '(:flap "ʡ̯") ) do
    (add-sound :pharyngeal (car e) (cadr e)))
; Glottal Pulmonic Consonants
(loop for e in (list
                    '(:plosive "ʔ")
                    '(:fricative "h") '(:fricative "ɦ") ) do
    (add-sound :glottal (car e) (cadr e)))
```

Comment: what exactly do you do to get the error?

Comment: I run clisp.exe /path/to/file.lisp where the file contains the above example. I can post more of the file, but it's really not going to be relevant.

Comment: good, can you insert "`-E UTF-8`" between "`clisp.exe`" and "`/path/to/file.lisp`" to get "`clisp.exe -E UTF-8 /path/to/file.lisp`"?

Comment: Yes I can, but you are stretching OOTB beyond credulity at that point. The answer to my question is then: "No" There is no way to do what I am doing in CLisp.

Comment: Could you please specify your limitations explicitly? Can you pass arguments to clisp? Can you create an init file? Can you dump an image? Can you create a _second_ file in addition to the one you are running?

Comment: Please see "note" inside "summary" in my answer: once the file is opened (and is being read &c) you cannot change _how_ it is being read, so you have to do something _before_ your file is read.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, no. I cannot do any of those things.

I want to type (setf x "blah blah UTF-8 CHAR blah blah") and have it work without having to edit the init file, or pass a special command line argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Summary

Either

- use the OS:

  - [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318716(v=vs.85).aspx): [How do I view and change the system locale settings to use my language of choice?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml)
  - [Unix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html): [How to change locale environment variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74618/31443)

  **OR**
- run CLISP with [`-E UTF-8` command line argument](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-enc) (`clisp.exe -E UTF-8 /path/....`), **OR**
- set the [default encodings](http://clisp.org/impnotes/encoding.html#enc-dflt) in the [init file](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-norc).
  **Note** that setting these variables **inside** your lisp file which errors out will *NOT* help because by the time CLISP reads the variables, the file has already been opened in the wrong external format.

## [CLISP FAQ: What do charset errors mean?](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-enc-err)

This means that you are trying to read (“invalid byte”) or write (“character cannot be represented”) a non-ASCII character from (or to) a character stream which has ASCII [`:EXTERNAL-FORMAT`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/open.html#extfmt). The default is described in [-Edomain encoding](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-enc).

This may also be caused by filesystem access. If you have files with names incompatible with your [`CUSTOM:*PATHNAME-ENCODING*`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/encoding.html#enc-dflt), filesystem access (e.g., `DIRECTORY`) will `SIGNAL` this `ERROR`. You will need to set `CUSTOM:*PATHNAME-ENCODING*` or pass `-Edomain encoding` to CLISP. Using a “1:1” encoding, such as `CHARSET:ISO-8859-1`, should help you avoid this error.

Please see the official site for full documentation.

PS. [You now owe me 10 zorkmids](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine)

PPS. Your code `(list '(...) '(...) ...)` looks weird, you might want to replace it with `'((...) (...) ...)`. I mean, your works too, it's just bad style.

Comment: I do appreciate this answer, but I have already read all of these things. I am well aware of why the problem exists, I simply don't know how to fix the problem. There is a disconnect between knowing the problem and knowing how precisely to fix it in Lisp, specifically without having to use -Edomain encoding.

I have also tried using the various CUSTOM:*BLAH-ENCODING* variables and setting them such as `(setf CUSTOM:*MISC-ENCODING* (make-encoding :charset charset:utf-8))`

PS: You now owe me a credit of 6 zorkmids to be applied to a response.

Comment: I appreciate your time and trouble, but I understood all of this. I simply don't know HOW to do it. Those files do not say HOW to do it, only WHAT to do. There is a distinction.

My example, the HOW to do it in ruby is: 

Write this line: # encoding UTF-8

Is there an equivalent line is Lisp if so WHAT is the line. Not the concept behind the line, or how or why it exists, but what is it.

Comment: Is there any implementation of common Lisp that can handle input in UTF-8? And I mean, can a script file be written, with strings hard coded into it, where the strings include UTF-8 characters? That does not require a special commandline argument?

Comment: First, which of the two alternative instructions in the "Summary" is unclear? Second, your reference to Ruby does not help be as I do not use it. Third, had you specified what you know and don't in the question, I might have been able to give a more targeted response right away.

Comment: CLISP _can_ and _does_ handle UTF-8 OOTB. All you need to do is learn how to use it.